# Size of char pointer array from function

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, char, size

Using this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printSize(char *messages[]) {
    printf("%d", sizeof(messages) / sizeof(char *));
}

int main(void) {

    printf("Size when through passing direct to function: ");
    printSize((char *[]){"Zero", "One", "Two", "Three"});
    printf("\n");

    printf("Size when calculating in main: %d\n", sizeof((char *[]){"Zero", "One", "Two", "Three"}) / sizeof(char *));

    return 1;
}
```

I get output:

```
Size when through passing direct to function: 1
Size when calculating in main: 4
```

I understand there is no way to get the correct amount of elements in a char* array, but I am curious as to why they are giving different results.

Comment: Arrays decay into pointers. You are getting the size of the pointer in your first example.

Comment: This is not a duplicate. I am asking why different answers are given, not how to get the amount of elements in the array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use an array as a parameter to a function, it "decays" to a pointer to the first element of the array. Since `messages` is an array of pointers to `char`, when the array is passed to the function, it becomes a pointer to a pointer to a char. This happens even though you are specifying it as an array in your parameter list; that is just how the language works.

So in `void printSize()`, when you use `sizeof(messages)`, you get the size of a pointer. You are dividing that by the size of another pointer `sizeof (char*)`. On your system, the size of a pointer is 4 bytes in both cases, so the result you get is 4 / 4, i.e., 1.

In `main()`, however, your array of `char*` is defined as, and treated as, an array. When the `sizeof()` operator is applied to an array, you get the size of all the bytes in the entire array. What is this an array of? It's an array of four pointers to `char`. Each pointer has the size 4. So the total size of the array is 4 * 4 = 16 bytes. You are dividing this 16 by the size of a single pointer to char, which is 4. So you are getting the result 16 / 4, i.e. 4 as the answer in `main()`.

Comment: Much clearer answer, relating directly to what I asked (without rudeness). Thanks, marked as correct.

Comment: One small question, is it better practice to write (char **messages) instead of (char *messages[]) since the first will just decay to the second.

Comment: It's a religious war. Some people say `char** messages` is better because it more exactly represents the parameter as it is received by the called function. Others say that `char* messages[]` is better because it more exactly represents what the parameter is from the calling function's point of view. I don't take sides in religious wars. :-)

Answer (score 4):

1. It's because `char *messages[]` is just syntactic sugar for `char **messages`, so you're just getting the size of a pointer, not the size of your whole array.
2. You can't, without passing the size along as another parameter.

You should check out the comp.lang.c FAQ section on [Arrays & Pointers](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/index.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I still don't understand why both are giving different numbers.

Comment: Did you read the link?  Specifically [6.21](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryparmsize.html)?  It's literally *exactly* your question.